# How to change time axis interval on LightWeightChart of TradingView?

Tags: lightweight-charts

Recently, I'm developing stock information web application via TtradingView Chart library.
But, I don't know how to change X-Axis interval on LightWeightChart.  I want to change to bellows.

from
09:00,  09:35, 10:18, 11:03

to
09:00,   09:30,  10:00, 10:30

I saw the TradingView docs and Issues tab on github. But above info does not found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for that so far. The grid is based the data you provided to the chart so if your data has gaps or too inconsistent data items within similar periods you will see such picture on the chart. The grid is trying to keep the same space (or similar; in pixels) between displayed values.

So you can either have inconsistent points or spaces and from UX perspective it looks like having spacing consistency is better rather than points one